# Entendiendo las especificaciones de protocolos en red

Tags: servidor

Quisiera entender la típica tabla de formato de un mensaje de comunicación en red, en la especificación de un protocolo cualquiera.

Por ejemplo (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3561.txt):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|     Type      |R|A|    Reserved     |Prefix Sz|   Hop Count   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                     Destination IP address                    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                  Destination Sequence Number                  |
```

¿Qué significa cada columna? ¿Es un byte? ¿Un bit?

Y, lo que me desconcierta aún más, no sé cómo interpretar las filas. Se supone que un mensaje es lineal, un bit tras otro, asi que no entiendo cḿo interpretar las filas.

Agradecería también si me pudieran mostrar un ejemplo de cómo implementarlo en un lenguaje de programación cualquiera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso que muestras cada columna representa un bit. Eso también queda obvio si revisas que tipos de datos contienen los campos - un IP de 32 bits tiene mucho sentido, un IP con 32 bytes sería un poco exagerado ;)

Los datos son lineales - la segunda fila es bit 32-63, la tercera 64-95 etc.

En el caso del RREP entonces significa:

- type: 1 byte, valor 2
- flags: 2 byte de eso 1 bit flag repair, 1 bit flag ACK, ultimpos 5 bit prefix
- hops: 1 byte (el máximo de los saltos hacía el peer
- IP destino: 4 byte
- ...

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, todo claro.